# Unable to cast object of type 'UserGroup to UserPrincipal in AD on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory

Hi i am using AD credentials for Login MVC application.This project is working on Local perfectly fine, but when I am trying to run on IIS its gives me error

> **Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type
>   'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.**

I tried every single solution which was on google but cant resolve this issue. Please help.
 Here is my LDAP class where I am getting current user

```
    public static bool UserIsMemberOfGroups(string username, string[] groups)
    {
        /* Return true immediately if the authorization is not
        locked down to any particular AD group */
        if (groups == null || groups.Length == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Verify that the user is in the given AD group (if any)
        using (var context = BuildPrincipalContext())
        {
            var userPrincipal = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context,
                 IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                 username);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                //if (userPrincipal != null)
                //{
                if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context, IdentityType.Name, group))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                // }
                //else
                //{

                //    return false;
                //}

            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static PrincipalContext BuildPrincipalContext()
    {
        string container = LDAPHelper.GetLDAPContainer();
       // return new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        return new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, container);
    }
```

Here is my Login Controller where I am calling this class based on Username, Password and group in AD

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [AuthorizeAD(Groups = "IT")]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModelView Login, string returnURL)
    {
        string serverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADConnectionString"];

        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (LDAPHelper.UserIsMemberOfGroups(Login.UserName, groups: new[] { "IT" }))
                {
                    if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login.UserName, Login.Password))
                    {
                        Session["Mnemonic"] = Login.UserName;
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Login.UserName, Login.RememberMe);
                        var v = UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName.ToString() + UserPrincipal.Current.Surname.ToString();
                        Session["UserFullName"] = v;
                        // todo use var userPrincipal name in header
                    }
                    #region This code is for remember only

                    //if (this.Url.IsLocalUrl(returnURL) && returnURL.Length > 1 && returnURL.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    //{

                    //    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "ITSMSearch");
                    //}

                    #endregion
                    else
                    {
                        Session["Error"] = "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
                        return this.View(Login);
                    }
                    Session["UserName"] = Login.UserName;

                    return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "ITSMSearch");
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["Error"] = "You are not a part of this group. Please confirm with support team.";
                    return this.View(Login);
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException e)
            {
                if (Session["Mnemonic"] == null || Session["Mnemonic"] == "")
                {
                    Session["Error"] = "Sorry you are not part of our AD. Please use valid credentials.Thanks.";
                }
                else
                {
                    // Session["Error"] = e.GetErrorText();
                    Session["Error"] = e.InnerException + e.Message;
                    }

                   return this.View(Login);
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

and in web.config

```
    <connectionStrings>
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://xxx.domain.org:389/DC=domain,DC=org" />
<add name="ITSM_Entities" connectionString="data source=zzz;initial catalog=xyz;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <system.web>
   <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/LoginPage/Login" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please highlight the line where you're getting this error. It's tough to find in this much of code.

Comment: I am not getting this error on my local. Its working perfectly fine on my local, but giving me error on IIS. So not sure in which line it is creating error. i tried to debug code like firstly remove group ("IT"), just connectivity with AD credentials without any groups but still show that error. Please help.

Comment: Try to enable debug mode for your web application, and then identify the line which is throwing this error.